# InnerHTML is not working with IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, select, innerhtml

I've a problem, I've a contact form and it has a drop down select to choose the subject of the contact, It's working on firefox but not on IE... can u help plz,

JS Part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jobhtml = "<td class='style1'>Job Reference:</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><label><input type='text' name='job-reference' id='textfield4' /></label></td>";
var orderhtml = "<td class='style1'>Item Reference:</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><label><input type='text' name='order-id' id='textfield4' /></label></td>";
function change()
{
   switch (document.getElementById("select").value)
   {
      case "job":
      document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = jobhtml;
      break;
      case "order":
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = orderhtml;
      break;
      default:
      document.getElementById("change").innerHTML="";
      break;
   }
}
</script>
```

HTML Parts:

```
 <tr>
          <td><span class="style1">Subject</span></td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td><label>
            <select name="select" id="select" onchange="change();">
              <option>Please select</option>
              <option>Meeting</option>
              <option>Call</option>
              <option value="order">Order</option>
              <option value="job">Apply for a position</option>
              <option>Testimonials</option>
              <option>Complains</option>
            </select>
          </label></td>
        </tr>
          <tr id="change" name="change">

        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done much simpler with jQuery. If you are open to that idea.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#select').change(function(){
       switch($(this).val()){
           case "job":
               $('#change').html(jobhtml);
               break;
           ...other cases...
       }
   });
});
```

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VZspM/)

Answer (score 2):

IE does not support `innerHTML` for `<tr>`. Do it like this:

```
<tr>
    <td><div id="change"></div></td>
</tr>
```

http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/46764-solved-innerhtml-tr-not-working-ie.html

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Support issue 239832](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239832)

You cannot set `innerHTML` on table elements other than cells.

There are plenty of better solutions. What I would do is something like this:

```
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Subject</td>
      <td><select onChange="change(this.value);">...</select></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Job Reference</td>
      <td>............</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Item Reference</td>
      <td>............</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('tbl'),
        tbd = tbl.tBodies;
    tbd[0].style.display = tbd[1].style.display = "none";
    window.change = function(val) {
      tbd[0].style.display = val == "job" ? "" : "none";
      tbd[1].style.display = val == "order" ? "" : "none";
    };
  })();
</script>
```

Basically divide the table into different bodies, and then show/hide them based on the selected value. This has the added bonus of being compatible if JavaScript is disabled (although it requires a bit more user intuition).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that is a known BUG:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

By the way i suggest you to use jquery:

document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = jobhtml;

became

$("#change").html(jobhtml); <-- better no?

ps: i suppouse that jquery use innerHTML..so should don't solve that problem..